# How to properly handle "existing connection forcibly closed"

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, networking, tcp

I have created a Multi-Threaded TCP Server. When a client disconnected I receive the

"existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" error.

What is the best method to handle the disconnect of a remote client, besides catching the error?

Comment: ...it all depends on what your server should do (or should not do) when the client disconnects unexpectedly. Tell us, and also show us **what you have tried so far** to achieve the expected behaviour of the server...

Comment: @elgonzo When the client disconnects I would like the server to discard the connection. Without errors.

Comment: From your question i deduce that you are already able to catch the error. What stops you from discarding this connection (whatever you understand as "discarding") when catching the error?

Comment: @elgonzo - Nothing does, that is what I am currently doing. I was wondering if there was a more "correct" way to handle this besides a simple catch. =D

Comment: The way you asked your question is more like an invite to a somewhat opinion-based discussion - something SO is not the right place for. If you have a concrete problem with your code then SO is the right place to ask. Quite possibly one can come up with different approaches to to deal with an unexpected client disconnect, possibly all of them "correct" in their own way -- but as said, this would be an opinion-based discussion, not really fitting into a question-answer format like SO. To cut a long story short -- if your code properly does what you want it to do, then don't worry :)

Comment: @elgonzo Well ... it functions ... but it puts ugly huge error messages into my log >.<.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Server is handle the connection to wait for incoming data :

Either when you read from the Socket or the NetworkStream the Read function will return 0 which clearly identify you has been disconnected from the remote client.

```
NetworkStream in = ...; 
...
readed = await in.ReadAsync(buffer, count, available);
if( readed == 0 ){
   // we are disconnected.
}
```

Comment: When the client disconnects I would like the server to discard the connection. Without errors.